# Not able to run andengine in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, andengine

I tried with small game using andeninge..Its working in Window XP system. Same project if I import or create a new project using andeninge I get run time error like

```
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m2f/com.m2f.AndengineActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:50)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-25 17:34:43.854: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

sample code:

```
public class DemoGame1 extends BaseGameActivity {

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

But android application is working fine(Its print HelloWorld) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have andengine running on 3 different Win7 Machines. I don't think the OS is the problem. Could you post the constructor for your game Activity Class so we can see what line is causeint the trouble? Also - are you using GLES2 or GLES1?

== Update ==

Okay - the problem is simple. You are not returning an engine in the onLoadEngine function. You are returning null. So when the game tries to initiate it calls methods of a null object. In short - your demo game does not contain enough to work.

At the very least you must define an engine and a camera. I expect you will also need a scene, since nothing will be rendered without it.

Then to actually see something on screen you will need to load some textures in the onLoadResources, and create at least one scene and some sprites in onLoadScene.

I recommend downloading the Andengine Examples source, and check out the MovingBallExample.java as a "Hello World" for andengine. Its really really simple.

AS for the GL version - you are using one or the other. There are two major revisions of the andengine library, know informally as GLES1 and GLES2. If you got the code recently from github you have GLES2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version of eclipse? The same version of the android SDK? Adt-plugin?version of the API level? GLES 2.0? Same version of AndEngine?

Check the version of everything and make sure they are the last ones and/or are compatible between them like platform-tools and adt-plugin